# rqt_graph in UsingRqtconsleRoslaunch tutorial not working

Tags: ros, rqt-graph, launch-file

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently in the process of going through the tutorials so I can get a better understanding of ROS.

I'm currently on tutorial 8 in the beginning tutorials

The problem I'm getting is at the last step when I use the command `rqt_graph`

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch

At the step where I'm using the launch file to launch 2 turtles. That works fine. Afterwards i use the rostopic pub command to get the turtles to go in a circle continuously. That works fine as well. However when I use `rqt_graph` I get the following error

```
angelo@angelo-Satellite-S55t-B:~$ rqt_graph
PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_graph/RosGraph#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 116, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 202, in restore_settings
    self._refresh_rosgraph()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 226, in _refresh_rosgraph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 259, in _update_graph_view
    self._redraw_graph_view()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 292, in _redraw_graph_view
    same_label_siblings=True)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/dot_to_qt.py", line 254, in dotcode_to_qt_items
    subgraph_nodeitem = self.getNodeItemForSubgraph(subgraph, highlight_level)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/dot_to_qt.py", line 83, in getNodeItemForSubgraph
    bb = subgraph.attr['bb'].strip('"').split(',')
KeyError: 'bb'
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Btw I'm using ROS indigo and Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200622/rqt_graph-in-usingrqtconsleroslaunch-tutorial-not-working/) by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

with roscore and the tutorial nodes running.

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-12**:
Ok that worked. Thanks!

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-01-13**:
Glad I could help, please upvote and mark the answer as correct if possible. :)